# Flashloan Arbitrage error 'SafeERC20: low-level call failed'

Tags: transactions, erc-20, javascript, flash-loans, arbitrage

So I finally am almost finished with my flashloan arbitrage how ever when I run it I get this error

```
'SafeERC20: low-level call failed'
```

here is my contract code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.4;

import "https://github.com/sushiswap/sushiswap/blob/master/contracts/uniswapv2/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router01.sol";
import { ILendingPool, ILendingPoolAddressesProvider, IERC20 } from "./Interfaces.sol";
import { FlashLoanReceiverBase } from "./FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol";
import { Withdrawable } from "./Withdrawable.sol";

/** 
!!!
Never keep funds permanently on your FlashLoanReceiverBase contract as they could be 
exposed to a 'griefing' attack, where the stored funds are used by an attacker.
!!!
 */

    contract FlashloanSushiswapToQuickswap is FlashLoanReceiverBase, Withdrawable {

    address Sushiswap_Router = 0x1b02dA8Cb0d097eB8D57A175b88c7D8b47997506;
    address Quickswap_Router = 0xa5E0829CaCEd8fFDD4De3c43696c57F7D7A678ff; 
    address Tether = 0xc2132D05D31c914a87C6611C10748AEb04B58e8F;
    address Wmatic = 0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270;
    uint256 Amount = ( 1000000 * 1e18 );

    IERC20 token;

    constructor(ILendingPoolAddressesProvider _addressProvider) 
    FlashLoanReceiverBase(_addressProvider) {
        }
     /**
     * @dev This function must be called only be the LENDING_POOL and takes care of 
     repaying
     * active debt positions, migrating collateral and incurring new V2 debt token debt.
     *
     * @param assets The array of flash loaned assets used to repay debts.
     * @param amounts The array of flash loaned asset amounts used to repay debts.
     * @param premiums The array of premiums incurred as additional debts.
     * @param initiator The address that initiated the flash loan, unused.
     * @param params The byte array containing, in this case, the arrays of aTokens and 
     aTokenAmounts.
     */


function executeOperation(
    address[] calldata assets,
    uint256[] calldata amounts,
    uint256[] calldata premiums,
    address initiator,
    bytes calldata params
)
    external
    override
    returns (bool)
{     
    // This contract now has the funds requested.
    // Your logic goes here.

   uint Start = IERC20(Tether).balanceOf(address(this));
    token.approve(Sushiswap_Router, Amount);
    token.approve(Quickswap_Router, Amount);

    address[] memory path1 = new address[](2);
    path1[0] = address(Tether);
    path1[1] = address(Wmatic);

    IUniswapV2Router01(Sushiswap_Router).swapExactTokensForTokens
    (Amount, Amount, path1, address(this), block.timestamp + 300);

    address[] memory path2 = new address[](2);
    path2[0] = address(Wmatic);
    path2[1] = address(Tether);

    IUniswapV2Router01(Quickswap_Router).swapExactTokensForTokens
    (Amount, Amount, path2, address(this), block.timestamp + 300);

    uint End = IERC20(Tether).balanceOf(address(this));
    require(End > Start, "No Profit Made");

    // At the end of your logic above, this contract owes
    // the flashloaned amounts + premiums.
    // Therefore ensure your contract has enough to repay
    // these amounts.

    // Approve the LendingPool contract allowance to *pull* the owed amount
    for (uint i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
        uint amountOwing = amounts[i]+(premiums[i]);
        IERC20(assets[i]).approve(address(LENDING_POOL), amountOwing);
    }

    return true;
}

function _flashloan(address[] memory assets, uint256[] memory amounts) internal {
    address receiverAddress = address(this);

    address onBehalfOf = address(this);
    bytes memory params = "";
    uint16 referralCode = 0;

    uint256[] memory modes = new uint256[](assets.length);

    // 0 = no debt (flash), 1 = stable, 2 = variable
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
        modes[i] = 0;
    }

    LENDING_POOL.flashLoan(
        receiverAddress,
        assets,
        amounts,
        modes,
        onBehalfOf,
        params,
        referralCode
    );
}

/*
 *  Flash loan wei amount worth of `_asset` 304061637379130
 */
function flashloan(address _asset, uint256 _amount) public {
    bytes memory data = "";
    uint amount = _amount;

    address[] memory assets = new address[](1);
    assets[0] = _asset;

    uint256[] memory amounts = new uint256[](1);
    amounts[0] = ( amount * 1e18 );

    _flashloan(assets, amounts);
}

}
```

my javascript code is like this

```
var ethers = require('ethers');
var IUniswapV2Router02 = require('./IUniswapV2Router02.json')
var SushiToQuick = require('./SushiToQuick.json');
var QuickToSushi = require('./QuickToSushi.json');
const maticProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(procces.env.provider_url);

const TETHER = '0xc2132D05D31c914a87C6611C10748AEb04B58e8F';
const WMATIC = '0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270';
const TETHER_ = ['0xc2132D05D31c914a87C6611C10748AEb04B58e8F'];

  const Amount = '1000000';
  const Amount_ = ['1000000'];
  const Premiums = ['1'];

  const SushiToQuickflashloanAddress = "0x4Ccb64D17eB9DaB48A5F0C51a27fC1E277708D69";
  const QuickToSushiFlashloanAddress = "0x50332903B054d381cD1De30166683dA4A6d79174";
  const SushiRouterAddress = "0x1b02dA8Cb0d097eB8D57A175b88c7D8b47997506";
  const QuickRouterAddress = "0xa5E0829CaCEd8fFDD4De3c43696c57F7D7A678ff";

  const private_key = process.env.privateKey;
  const myAccount = "0x39D780E2e82b76fCE187C5d4b080E2DD6b32F746";

  if ( private_key === undefined) { throw new Error("Private key is not defined");
  }

 async function SushiTetherToWmaticFlashloanArbitrage() {
 const signer = new ethers.Wallet( private_key, maticProvider );
 const SushiToQuickFlashloan = new ethers.Contract(SushiToQuickflashloanAddress, 
SushiToQuick, signer);
const SushiRouter = new ethers.Contract(SushiRouterAddress, IUniswapV2Router02, signer);
const QuickRouter = new ethers.Contract(QuickRouterAddress, IUniswapV2Router02, signer);
const SushiScanTetherToWmatic = await SushiRouter.getAmountsOut(Amount, [TETHER, 
WMATIC]);
const QuickScanTetherToWmatic = await QuickRouter.getAmountsOut(Amount, [TETHER, WMATIC]);


       if (SushiScanTetherToWmatic >= ( QuickScanTetherToWmatic + ( QuickScanTetherToWmatic / 100 
       * 1 ))) {

       console.log("Trade Is Profitable")  

        await SushiToQuickFlashloan.flashloan(TETHER, Amount, { gasPrice: 
        ethers.utils.parseUnits('30000', 'gwei'), gasLimit: 2500000 
        } )
       SushiToQuickflashloanAddress, 0x000000000, { gasPrice: 
       ethers.utils.parseUnits('30000', 
      'gwei'), gasLimit: 2500000 } )

     }

   else { console.log("No Opportunities For This Trade");

       }
    }

 SushiTetherToWmaticFlashloanArbitrage();
```

I don't know what it could be as the tokens are being approved and the get amounts out should make sure that it's profitable so I don't seem to know why it doesn't work here is the failed transaction https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x9eccd2f85e4154fb186c410557906adcd7222548e2b3cbbee2c55f9bfae69f67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out the`IERC20 token;` part of the smart contract had nothing to refer to so I wasn't approving anything